# Any ideas on how to prove that this subset is a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Prove or disprove that each given subset of P5 is a subspace of P5 under the usual operations.

{ p ∈ $P_5$|where p is an odd-degree polynomial (highest-order nonzero term has odd degree) }

Any ideas on how to approach checking for the three conditions for this set?

Comment: You've asked lots of homework-like questions about subspaces in the last 24-hours. This website is not meant to do people's homework. If you are genuinely having trouble understanding the concepts, please show that you have put effort toward your problems.

Comment: **Hint:**  Both $x^3$ and $x^3+x^2$ are odd-degree polynomials.

Comment: @Riley Yes. That is correct. Am not looking for the exact answer though. Only not wasting time on being stuck. A starting point or a way of looking at it would really be sufficient!!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** (*by JMoravitz*) Both $x^3$ and $x^3+x^2$ are odd-degree polynomials.